# orthonormal basis such that entry wise product of any pair of vectors is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $e_1=[1\ 0]^T$, $e_2=[0\ 1]^T$, $v_1=[\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}]^T$, and $v_2=[\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\ -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}]^T$. Both $(e_1,e_2)$ and $(v_1,v_2)$ can be an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, there is a difference between them: the elementwise or Hadamard product of $e_1$ and $e_2$ is zero vector but this is not the case for $v_1$ and $v_2$.

I am looking for some information about orthonormal bases such that the Hadamard product of each pair of vectors becomes the zero vector.

I can describe them as follows:
If $B=(v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n)$ is a basis, then $$v_i^2 \cdot v_j^2=0\ \ \ \ i\ne j$$ $$v_i \cdot v_j=1\ \ \ \ i= j$$

Do they have a special name? Do you know any references to study them?

Comment: Isn't the canonical basis the only such basis? Order the $v_j$ such that the first entry of $v_1$ is nonzero, then the first entry in all the other $v_j$ is zero. Now reorder the $v_j$, $j>1$ so that $v_2$ has it's second entry nonzero (one of them has to have this property), and then the second entry in all the others is 0. Continue in this way, to see that our reordering gives the canonical basis.